# why does my django project keep showing no assignment even after upload them?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I' unable to show the error as there is no traceback, there seems to be a problem in my code that I am unable to sort. My project is assignment submissions platform, and in the student submission page it shows that there are no assignments even though I ahve created alot of them.

I'm pasting my code below, please do have a look and any sort of help would be really appreciated.

Views.py

```
# for Teacher to create assignment.
@login_required
def upload_assignment(request):
    assignment_uploaded = False
    teacher = request.user.Teacher
    students = Student.objects.filter(user_student_name__teacher=request.user.Teacher)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AssignmentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            upload = form.save(commit=False)
            upload.teacher = teacher
            students = Student.objects.filter(user_student_name__teacher=request.user.Teacher)
            upload.save()
            upload.student.add(*students)
            assignment_uploaded = True
    else:
        form = AssignmentForm()
    return render(request,'upload_assignment.html',{'form':form,'assignment_uploaded':assignment_uploaded})

# for students to view all the assingments 
    @login_required
    def class_assignment(request):
        student = request.user.Student
        assignment = SubmitAssignment.objects.filter(student=student)
        assignments_list = [x.submitted_assignment for x in assignment]
        return render(request,'class_assignment.html',{'student':student,'assignment_list':assignment_list})
```

Models.py

```
class logger(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Student(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(logger,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,related_name='Student')
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    roll_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['roll_no']

class Teacher(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(logger,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,related_name='Teacher')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name="teachers", through="StudentsInClass")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('teacher_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class StudentsInClass(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher,related_name="class_teacher",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,related_name="user_student_name",on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('teacher','student')

class ClassAssignment(models.Model):
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student,related_name='student_assignment')
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher,related_name='teacher_assignment',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    assignment_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    assignment = models.FileField(upload_to='assignments')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.assignment_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

Forms.py

```
# Form to create updating assignment for teachers        
class AssignmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = ClassAssignment
        fields = ['assignment_name','assignment']
```

class_assignment.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
    
    {% if student.student_assignment.count == 0 %}
      <h2>No assignments Yet</h2>
    {% else %}
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Assignment Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Uploaded By</th>
            <th scope="col">Uploaded Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Download</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for assignment in student.student_assignment.all %}
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
              <td>{{ assignment.assignment_name }}</td>
              <td>{{ assignment.teacher }}</td>
              <td>{{ assignment.created_at }}</td>
              <td><a href="{{ assignment.assignment.url }}" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
              {% if assignment in assignment_list %}
                <td>Submitted</td>
              {% else %}
                <td><a href="{% url 'submit_assignment' id=assignment.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a></td>
              {% endif %}
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

I'll explain the working of the code a bit, the thing is that the student must be in the StudentsinClass model to view the class assignments, even after adding the student in it, when I visit the assignment page with the same account, it shows no assignments yet, I think there is something wrong in my logic because there are no errors or tracebacks.

Any help would be really appreciated and please comment if you need me to show any other part of my code as well.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fairly well but I can't tell for sure until I run it. I would strongly recommend you write print statements returning the data passed in and to check if it even got to `if form.is_valid()` in the first place.

For example:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
    print('post method')
    form = AssignmentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():
         print('form passed')
         upload = form.save(commit=False)
         upload.save()
         print('form successfully saved')
      else:
         print('form not valid')
else:
   print('not a POST method')
```

Try to also edit your question to show us how you're rending out the form in HTML - there might be a bug or error there.

Comment: Hi, I think that part is working because in the admin panel you can see the assignment added there.

Comment: Also, I have added the code for rending html files in view.py only

Comment: The form seems to be working cause it printed post method, form passed, saved

Comment: nice  are you seeing the new object created in the db?